# In a Swift macOS app, what would be an elegant solution for implementing a window with choices bound to UserDefaults that has a Cancel Button?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I have a Cocoa Swift macOS app, not document based. I have to present some persistent choices to the user, and I would like to use NSUserDefaults and bindings. Everything is fine, except that in this options sheet window I have a "Cancel" button. I would expect that the changes made to the settings (for example a checkbox) could not persist if the user has pressed the "Cancel" button, but I can't imagine a possible elegant implementation to make this happen. When using Core Data, this scenario is very well handled using a subcontext, but in my case I would like to avoid Core Data because I just have a few simple options. I hope there is a technique that I am missing that can solve the problem. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Group the settings in a dictionary, read, edit, save if ok. Instead of a window controller I would present a view controller and bind to `representedObject` or a property.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working, perhaps not so elegant implementation:

```
- (IBAction)userDidPressSetMapOptions:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSStoryboard *mapOptionsStoryboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MapOptions" bundle:nil];
    
    self.mapOptionsWindowController = [mapOptionsStoryboard instantiateInitialController];
    
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    NSDictionary *currentDict = [userDefaults dictionaryRepresentation];
    
    [self.view.window beginSheet:self.mapOptionsWindowController.window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
        
        if (returnCode == NSModalResponseCancel) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                
            
            [currentDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
               
                [userDefaults setValue:obj forKey:key];
                
            }];
            });
        }
        
    }];
    
}
```

Nevertheless, I still would like a better answer. Thank you for your attention.

BTW: I have used dispatch_async because otherwise the checkboxes, for example, turn back to their previous setting before the window closes after a cancel, which is confusing.